# Search within search result in Azure?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Is this possible in Azure Cognitive search?

I am writing an Web app using React JS with Search functionality with Advance search also, but we want more search function within the result of standard search.

**This azure query will returns the first page (20 results) out of thousand result**

```
test search&highlightPreTag=<mark>&highlightPostTag=</mark>&highlight=content-10&$count=true&$top=20&$skip=20&facet=Category,count:200&facet=Department,count:200&facet=DocumentType,count:50&facet=DB,count:200&$filter=(search.in(Security, 'Default;Public;Shared', ';'))
```

**Sample array  data return**

[1] FileName: Test search0.pdf, Content: "test", Author: "test1"

[2] FileName: Test search1.pdf, Content: "test", Author: "test1"

[3] FileName: Test search1.pdf, Content: "test", Author: "test2"

[4] FileName: Test search1.pdf, Content: "test", Author: "test2"

.....
1000

Now the user will search in that specific query that returns thousand documents using Author field = "Test1" so the return would be all that matches the **Author** name in that **azure query**.

Is this possible in Azure Cognitive search? I tried looking in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/ and didn't find one.

My current idea is loop in all result (ex. 1000) and save it in state, but I think its not ideal

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @GauravMantri Updated my question, hopes my example make sense.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly your users will first perform a search for "test" in the Content field and then subsequently they would want to filter the search results by Author field. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the user want to do further search using the first result.

Comment: AFAIK, search within search is not supported. Just wondering if you can combine all the searches in a single query? You can use OData Filter to create really complex queries.

Comment: This is noted. I think I will take a look in OData Filter more. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-odata-filter-orderby-syntax. HTH.

Comment: Thanks will take a look into this.